# Understanding log.info()

Tags: scala, zio

Can you please explain what this **log.info** is doing here? Where can I see this log info for debugging purpose? In my existing project, it has been used at many places inside for loop. Thanks!

```
import java.io.{BufferedInputStream, FileInputStream}

import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.contravariantSemigroupal._
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.syntax.parallel._
import com.google.api.client.util.{DateTime => GDateTime}
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage
import com.leighperry.log4zio.Log.SafeLog
import zio.interop.catz._
import zio.{IO, Managed, ZIO}

def fileContentsToGcs(
     cfg: AppConfig,
     log: SafeLog[String],
     filepath: String
): List[String] = {
     val result: IO[FilesError, List[String]] =
     for {
     _ <- log.info(s"GCS file ${cfg.gcsBucketProject} ${cfg.gcsInputBucket} $filepath")

       // list of csv files
       contents <- expandedFileContents(log, cfg, filepath)
       _ <- log.info(s"GCS temp files $contents")
     } yield contents

   unsafeRun(result)
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what library this is?

Comment: We are using this library
```import com.leighperry.log4zio.Log.SafeLog```

Comment: Are you familiar with what a _monad_ is? If not, that'd be where to start. See the documentation on [IO in Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/2.x/datatypes/io) and [ZIO](https://zio.dev/version-1.x/overview/).